# Dropzone.css image preview has rounded corners with white background

Tags: css, dropzone.js, rounded-corners, dropzone

Had an issue with dropzone.css where after an image was uploaded it would display a thumbnail and round the corners, but the corners would be white.

To fix it I found and commented out the line below:

```
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview {
        /*background: white;*/ 
}
```

No idea why that would be in there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the css for `.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview` and comment out the background line like below:

```
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview {
        /*background: white;*/ 
}
```

Remember, if you are using .min to do it there aswell/instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the package container's css files or min css files.

Instead, just add markup to your site either using  or using your own css source file, with:

```css
.dropzone .dz-preview.dz-image-preview {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```